# Passenger Still Runs in Production Despite Everything Seeming to Be Correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, passenger

I'm running Passenger inside of the Phusion provided Docker container (https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker), and have set my Rails environment to a dev setting using the following:

```
docker run -rm -p 80:80 -e RAILS_ENV=development <image_name>
```

However, Passenger continues to only run in production mode. What would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue is that Passenger running in this container doesn't listen to the environment variable for RAILS_ENV, it only listens to PASSENGER_APP_ENV. It uses that environment variable to adjust the nginx.conf file. You can see this happening in this file (https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/blob/master/image/config/30_presetup_nginx.sh)

Setting BOTH variables solved the problem (RAILS_ENV is still used by other tools).

```
docker run -rm -p 80:80 -e RAILS_ENV=development -e PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development <image_name>
```